# Помогите решить задачу

Tags: алгоритм

Дана последовательность чисел. Известно что все числа в ней встречаются четное количество раз, кроме одного, которое встречается нечетное количество раз. Напишите программу, которая находит это число.
например: исходная последовательность:1,2,3,4,2,3,1,4,2,1,4,3,4,12,3,2,1,5,5,7,7,12,7,7,9,8,12,9,8
Искомое число :12

Comment: @DreamChild, HashCode – это же коллективный разум : ) Мне этот вопрос позволил размяться/отвлечься, а ответ @KoVadim заполнил пробел в моих базовых знаниях об алгоритмах. Может, кому-то ещё пригодится. Я не переоткрывал вопрос, но вижу только плюсы в этом событии.

Comment: я еще раз говорю, что закрыли не справедливо, я решал эту задачу и долго, 
но ничего кроме как перемножения и сложения в голову не пришло, по этому и обратился, 
но вы правы надо было написать какие варианты перебирать, а когда уже решение было найдено, я хотел сообщить сюда, но увы уже закрыли, хотя бы предупредили бы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это классическая задача которая решается с помощью xor (исключающего или). Все числа "ксорятся" последовательно. Благодаря свойствам xor, в конце будет нужно число. Это алгоритм имеет линейную сложность (в отличии от алгоритма [@Sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks) , который имеет квадратичную сложность (или в лучшем случае n*ln(n))).

Comment: Здорово, не пришло в голову такое решение! `XOR` хорош для поиска единственного значения. Вариант с массивом найдёт множественные.

Comment: [реализация решения на С для примера](http://ideone.com/CzbQAa)

Answer (score 1):

Можно идти по последовательности, и очередное число либо добавлять в массив, если его там ещё нет, либо стирать из массива, если такое там уже есть.

В конце в массиве останутся только те, которых нечётное число.

[Пример на JS](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/k8e9Lmox/).